# Error "a valid provisioning file for this executable was not found"

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, provisioning, provisioning-profile

I cant install the provisioning profile on my Ipad, the bundle identifier of the app is correct, the device is correct in provisioning portal, but everytime i try to build the Debug in my Ipad it says me "a valid provisioning file for this executable was not found", even if i try to manually input the correct bundle identifier on info.plist, doesnt work.
i already tried to re-authorize the device, via organizer but doesnt worked too.
I recriated and reinstalled the provisioning profile several times, but always get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your code signing settings in Xcode are correct.  Sounds like you are code signing with a provisioning profile that is different than the one you think.  Your debug signing should be done with your Dev profile and your release signing should be done with your Distribution profile.